# Tags for rows in a commutative diagram using tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Consider a commutative diagram such as

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools, tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            0 \rar & A \dar \rar & B \dar \rar & C \dar \rar & 0 &[3em] \text{(\textit{i})}\\
            0 \rar & A' \rar & B' \rar & C' \rar & 0 & \text{(\textit{ii})}
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I'd like to add labels to the rows of the diagram. Now, you'll agree that this solution is rather ugly. Is it possible to add labels to the rows that appear at the margin; i.e., instead of what you see, I'd like to have, e.g.,
[image]
Which I produced using

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath, tikz-cd}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{gather}
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            0 \rar \& |[alias=A]|  A \rar \& B \rar \& C \rar \& 0
        \end{tikzcd}\\
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            0 \rar \& A' \ar[from=A] \rar \& B' \rar \& C' \rar \& 0 
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

which is certainly not the way to go, since it is not particularly stable, and the proper alignment of the cells, which I was too lazy fore here, will be a mess.

Comment: Unrelated: your use of `\text` in the first example makes no sense at all. `\text` should never be used to make something non-italic, because that is not what `\text` does.

Comment: @daleif I always thought `\text` is for putting text in math, and a label is certainly closer to text than to math. And who tells you that I don't want the labels match the surrounding text shape? :P But yes, that's not the point of my question.

Comment: I only not it becase a **lot** of users seems to think that this is the right tool to write something update in math mode and as you mention it is not.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need tikz-cd for this kind of diagrams. Here is a way to  do it with `alignat`and `\rotatebox`.

*Unrelated*: you don't have to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`, since the latter does it for you.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{4}
            0 \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em}{} & A & \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em} {}& B & \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em}{} & C \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em} 0 \\[-1ex]
                             & \,\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{${} \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em}{}$} & & \,\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{${} \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em}{}$} & & \,\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{${} \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em}{}$} \notag \\[-1ex]
            0\xrightarrow{\hskip 2em}{} & A' &\xrightarrow{\hskip 2em} {}& B' & \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em}{} & C' \xrightarrow{\hskip 2em} 0
    \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, but what about more complicated diagrams?

Comment: @Bubaya: What do you mean exactly with ‘more complicated diagrams’? One I think of is the *Snake lemma* (a tool for Homological Algebra), which I make with `pstricks` preferably.

Comment: I'd say that the solution has several other problems; what do you do if the lengths of the entries largely differ? Then you'd have to adjust all the arrow lengths until it looks okay. How does pstricks come to help here?

Comment: @Bubaya: for the example I gave, I mainly thought  of the S-shaped arrow form the last non-zero term in the first row to the first non-zero term in the second row. This being said, in case of entries with different lengths, you can use the `psmatrix` environment. Each entry is a node and you can use node connections between these entries.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem of your second example is only the alignment, you can fix it.

This way, there is no problem when you reference the lines:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools, tikz-cd}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
If the problem of your second example is only the alignment, you can fix it. 

This way, there is no problem referencing the first
\eqref{eq:first} or the second line \eqref{eq:second}:

\begin{gather}
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,
    every cell/.append style={text centered}]
        0 \rar \& |[alias=A, text width=width("$A'$")]|A \rar \& |[text width=width("$B'$")]|B \rar \& |[text width=width("$C'$")]|C \rar \& 0\label{eq:first}
    \end{tikzcd}\\[5ex]
    \begin{tikzcd}[overlay, ampersand replacement=\&]
        0 \rar \& A' \ar[from=A] \rar \& B' \rar \& C' \rar \& 0\label{eq:second} 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a proof-of-concept since I'm not very familiar with the internals of AMSMath.

Note:

- This needs a node in column 1 for each row.
- If you shift this node up or down, the equation number will move with it vertically.
- The macros `\tag` and `\nonumber` won't work.
- The equation number will not be shifted down when the row is too long.
- Don't write anything before or after the TikZ-CD. The placement of the equation numbers are dependent of the diagram being in the horizontal middle of the line.
- Hyperref? Cleveref? Maybe.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools, tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{
  eqno per line/.style={
    /tikz/column 1/.append code=%
      \global\pgfutil@namelet{tikzcd@rowlabel@\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
                             {pgfutil@empty},
    /tikz/execute at end picture={%
      \pgfmathloop % simpler than \foreach
        \node[overlay,path only,anchor=base east,inner sep=+0pt,outer sep=+0pt](@)
        at(.5\linewidth,0|-\tikzcdmatrixname-\pgfmathcounter-1.base){%
          \@eqnswtrue\make@display@tag
          \expandafter\pgfutil@ifxempty
            \csname tikzcd@rowlabel@\pgfmathcounter\endcsname{}{%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ltx@label
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
              \csname tikzcd@rowlabel@\pgfmathcounter\endcsname}}};%
      \ifnum\pgfmathcounter<\pgfmatrixcurrentrow
      \repeatpgfmathloop}},
  every matrix/.append code={%
    \def\label##1{%
      \expandafter\xdef
        \csname tikzcd@rowlabel@\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\endcsname{##1}}}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment*{tikzcdeq}[1][]
  {\begin{equation*}\tikzcd[eqno per line,#1]}
  {\endtikzcd\end{equation*}}
\begin{document}
Lorem \ref{label3}
\begin{equation}
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}
ipsum \ref{label1}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[eqno per line]
  0 \rar & A \dar \rar & B \dar \rar & C \dar \rar & 0 \label{label1} \\
  0 \rar & A' \rar     & B' \rar     & C' \rar     & 0 \label{label2}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
dolor \eqref{label2}
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}
sit \eqref{label4}
\begin{tikzcdeq}
  0 \rar & A \dar \rar & B \dar \rar & C \dar \rar & 0 \label{label3} \\
  0 \rar & A' \rar     & B' \rar     & C' \rar     & 0 \label{label4}
\end{tikzcdeq}
amet.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If this doesn't work and two diagrams are really needed, we can measure the max width of each column and adjust the column widths (not the nodes') so that the vertical nodes align again.