# Strange behavior of tikz-cd with remember picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, remember

While trying to answer [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636448/tags-for-rows-in-a-commutative-diagram-using-tikz-cd), I found a strange behavior of TikZ-cd with `remember picture`.

If I compile the following code more times, the distance between the first and the second TikZ-cd increases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz-cd}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r] & |[alias=B]|B \ar[r] & C 
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        D\ar[r] & E \ar[from=B] \ar[r] & F  
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

First run:

[image]

Second run:

[image]

Third run:

[image]

Fourth run:

[image]

Fifth run:

[image]

Sixth run:

[image]

Seventh run:

[image]

and so on :D

What is the problem?

Comment: I would have guessed this would be covered by another Q&A on this site but I can't find one. But just the vertical arrow needs `overlay`. The bottom diagram grows in height since TikZ just measures how far the distance between the two pictures are and draws a line in that direction. But since this adds to the bounding box it just moves the diagram farther down. (As would `\dfrac` in a normal paragraph unless `\smash` is used.) And the distance between pictures becomes bigger, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for the explanation. I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the (simple) reason: `overlay` was missing.

From the TikZ manual:

> `/tikz/overlay=<boolean>` (default true) This option is mainly intended
> for use when nodes in other pictures are referenced, but you can also
> use it in other situations. The effect of this option is that
> everything within the current scope is not taken into consideration
> when the bounding box of the current picture is computed. You need to
> specify this option on all paths (or at least on all parts of paths)
> that contain a reference to a node in another picture. The reason is
> that, *otherwise, TikZ will attempt to make the current picture large*
> *enough to encompass the node in the other picture. However, on a*
> *second run of TeX this will create an even bigger picture, leading to*
> *larger and larger pictures.* Unless you know what you are doing, I
> suggest specifying the overlay option with all pictures that contain
> references to other pictures.

This works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{diagrams={remember picture}} 

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  A \rar \& |[alias=B]|B \ar[r] \& C 
\end{tikzcd}
\]\vspace{1ex}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[overlay, ampersand replacement=\&]
  D\ar[r] \& E \ar[from=B] \rar \& F  
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that:

- as muzimuzhi Z said in their comment, in this case, `\tikzcdset{diagrams={remember picture}}` is better than `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}`, because it appends options only to `tikzcd` diagram, hence non-`tikzcd` `tikzpicture`s are not affected
- as Qrrbrbirlbel said in their comment, only the second `tikzcd` (where the vertical arrow is) needs the `overlay` option.

Comment: `\tikzcdset{diagrams={remember picture, overlay}}` is better. It appends options to `every diagram` style which is used at the beginning of each `tikzcd` diagram, hence non-`tikzcd` `tikzpictures` are not affected.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ You're right, I copied from the MWE of the question I was trying to answer